# Graph API Findmeetingtimes not returning the resule if attendee count is more than 20

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Graph API Findmeetingtimes not returning the result if attendee count is more than 20 in the request

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "The number of attendees exceeds the maximum number of attendees supported",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3f4dec8c-ef7b-47f9-8b3e-c7da349da574",
            "date": "2018-09-06T12:54:09"
        }
    }
}

Comment: You can combine your commnent to your question details.

Answer (score 0):

The default maximum number of attendees supported is 20, so you get the exception.

If you want to query attendees more than 20, please query multiple times. For example, if you have 38 attendees, you can create twice request with 19 attendees for each time.